# ORSSerialPort serialRead in swift

Tags: macos, swift, arduino, orsserialport

I'm trying to work with ORSSerialPort in Swift. But I have problem with reading data from serial port. The trouble is wrong serialPort function implementation. Maybe this part would be helpful:

- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveResponse:(NSData *)responseData toRequest:(ORSSerialRequest *)request;

---

```
//Auduino code. Send data for request.
int incomingByte = Serial.read();
if (incomingByte = '1', DEC) {
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(t);
```

---

```
//OS X
class SerialController : NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {
    var port : ORSSerialPort

    init(path: String){
        port=ORSSerialPort(path: path)
        port.close()
    }

    func open(){
        port.baudRate=9600
        port.delegate=self
        port.open()
    }

    func close(){
        port.delegate=nil
        port.close()
    }

    func SendString(data: String){
        port.sendData(data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

  //I'm trying to figure out how do I need to read data from serial 
   func serialPort(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!, idReceiveResponse:(NSData *)responseData         toRequest:(ORSSerialRequest *)request) -> String {

        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            println(string)
            return(string)
        }
    }
```

---

```
    let myPort = SerialController(path: "/dev/tty.usbmodem14141")


    myPort.open()
    myPort.SendString("1")
    var dataFromSerial = myPort.serialPort //read
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy/paste your code, or retype it for the question? It has several errors that would cause it not to compile, but I don't think those are the errors that provoked your question.

The main issue is that `-serialPort:didReceiveResponse:toRequest:` will only be called if you previously sent an `ORSSerialRequest` using the `-sendRequest:` method. Since you're simply sending raw data, you need to implement `-serialPort:didReceiveData:` (or rather `serialPort(serialPort: ORSSerialPort!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)` since you're using Swift) instead.

You should take a look at the ORSSerialPortSwiftDemo sample project in the Examples folder if you haven't already.